# Rails webpacker can't find node version from nvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nvm

I'm getting this error when running rails server.

```
sh: 1: node: not found
sh: 1: nodejs: not found
Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

also when trying to install webpacker:install

```
sudo rails webpacker:install
sh: 1: node: not found
sh: 1: nodejs: not found
Node.js not installed. Please download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

I'm using nvm manage my node and it works fine.

`test_app4 [master] node -v
              v8.16.0`

How can i get rails to find my node instance from nvm?

EDIT:
If i install node via apt-get. Rails finds that node version which is found with `nodejs -v`. Just not sure why it doesn't find the nvm version.

Comment: Is `node` in your `PATH`? It seems like it might not be, but you'll have to check: `which node` for example.

Comment: Yeah it is on my PATH. `echo $PATH
/home/aman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/node:/home/aman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin`. Same as `which node`.

Comment: any solution for this? mine not using the nvm mentioned node version with cap deploy.